# Force docx file download via PHP corrupt

Tags: php, download, docx

I know there are a lot of mentions of this but I have tried all the suggestions and nothing seems to work.

I have this script to force download files, but when using docx formats it downloads ok but then says the file is corrupt. However word does manage to open it ok.

Does anyone know why the docx would keep saying there corrupt. I have double checked them by ftp them down from the server and they are fine and open first time.

```
$documentDir = '/home/';
$file = $_GET['d'];
$fileLocation = $documentDir.$file;
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileLocation)); 
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
readfile($fileLocation);
exit(0);
```

Comment: Does this work with other files for you?

Answer (score 2):

This script works for me.

Are you sure that all your documents are situated in `/home/` ?

Don't you mean the relative path `home/`

If this still doesn't work, can you please tell what's the size of the downloaded docx, and open that file in a text editor like sublime_text, the error will probably be written in there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try modifying disposition line and adding encoding line to ensure encoding is done correctly.

```
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8'en'$file");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

Comment: Thanks but that made no difference.